# Python Get N max values from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Assume we have dictionary:

```
items = {'a': 7, 'b': 12, 'c': 9, 'd': 0, 'e': 24, 'f': 10, 'g': 24}
```

I want to get another dictionary, containing 4 elements with maximum values. E.g. I expect to get:

```
subitems = {'e': 24, 'g': 24, 'b': 12, 'f': 10}
```

What will be most pythonic and efficient (memory consumption, execution speed - when f.e. I'll have dict with 1000000 elements) way to do this? Generators, lambdas, something another?

**Addition 1**: they are some similar questions:

[5 maximum values in a python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197315/5-maximum-values-in-a-python-dictionary)

[top values from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902665/top-values-from-dictionary)

And they also may contain a solutions, but they don't ask for most efficient, pythonic way to solve this especially on large data sets.

Comment: or this one [top values from dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902665/top-values-from-dictionary). Your call really.

Comment: @Lafexlos Well, I like the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902665/top-values-from-dictionary one better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) is always the correct answer when the question is "How do I get a small number of maximum values from a huge set of inputs?" It minimizes memory usage and CPU usage better than just about anything else you could do in Python, by using heaps. Example:

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter

n = 3

items = {'a': 7, 'b': 12, 'c': 9, 'd': 0, 'e': 24, 'f': 10, 'g': 24}

topitems = heapq.nlargest(n, items.items(), key=itemgetter(1))  # Use .iteritems() on Py2
topitemsasdict = dict(topitems)
```

`sorted` and slicing the result can win when the number of max items requested is a large percentage of the input, but for huge inputs and small numbers of max items, the memory savings of `heapq.nlargest` will win.

For the CS theory geeks, `heapq.nlargest`, for an input of size `n`, selecting the `k` max values, requires `O(n log k)` computation, and `k` storage. `sorted` followed by slicing requires `O(n log n)` computation and `n` storage. So for 1024 inputs and 4 selected items, work for `nlargest` is ~1024 * *2* computation with storage required of 4; `sorted` + slicing would be ~1024 * *10* computation with storage of 1024. In practice, Python's TimSort used in `sorted` has lower overhead than big-O notation can properly convey, and usually performs better than the big-O notation would indicate, which is why for, say, selecting the top 200 items out of 1024, `sorted` + slicing can still win, but `nlargest` lacks pathological degradation for huge inputs and outputs; it may be slower on occasion, but it's usually not much slower, where sorted can be faster, but it can also be *much* slower.

Answer (score 1):

Check the source code of [`collections.Counter.most_common()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l484) method. It shows the best solution. And of course, the best way is using `Counter()` instead of `{}`.

```
def most_common(self, n=None):
    '''List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
    common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

    >>> Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba').most_common(3)
    [('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]

    '''
    # Emulate Bag.sortedByCount from Smalltalk
    if n is None:
        return sorted(self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return _heapq.nlargest(n, self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```