# why does my sort function for a dictionary not sort it according to its values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys and values that are integers.

```
my_dict = {1:3,2:5,3:1}
```

I would like to sort my dictionary according to its values.

I found a very useful article here:
[5 maximum values in a python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197315/5-maximum-values-in-a-python-dictionary)

So, I tried what was suggested, which is to sort my_dict according to its values (in reverse):

```
sorted(my_dict,key=my_dict.get, reverse=True)
```

This DOES NOT seem to sort my_dict according to its values as suggested in the article. Any ideas why?

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Please show a [mre].

Comment: note `sorted` creates a new list, won't sort `my_dict` in place...

Comment: Also sorting a dictionary is beside the point, orders in dicts should not matter.

Comment: Dict doesnt have order, they have keys

Answer (score 0):

The returned values are indices of `my_dict`. You can get desired list by using `my_list = [my_dict[i] for i in sorted(my_dict,key=my_dict.get, reverse=True)]`.

Comment: Hi Nguyen, thanks- I think I wrote the wrong question. My intention is simply to sort the dictionary, so I would like the output to be {3:1, 1:3,2:5}

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is `sorted(my_dict.values(), reverse=True)`

Comment: Hi Julien, thanks- I think I wrote the wrong question. My intention is simply to sort the dictionary, so I would like the output to be {3:1, 1:3,2:5}

Comment: As I said sorting a dict makes little sense, the point of a dict is not to be ordered, if you care about the values, then sort the values... This sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, Dictionaries don't retain order. Ordered Dictionary do however

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_dict = my_dict = {1:3,2:5,3:1}
sorted_dict = OrderedDict({k:my_dict[k] for k in sorted(my_dict,key=my_dict.get)})
```

which will result in `sorted_dict` containing

```
OrderedDict([(3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 5)])
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use `my_list.append(sorted(my_dict, reverse=True)[:2])` it will append the two largest values to my_list.